# ExtJS 3 using the methods of a registered component

Tags: javascript, object, extjs, methods

I extended a tabpanel and registered it like such:

```
DVI.DviDashboard = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
initComponent: function(){
    Ext.apply(this, {
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [item1, item2]
    });

    DVI.DviDashboard.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

}
});

Ext.reg('dviDashboard', DVI.DviDashboard);
```

When rendered, I have a tabpanel with two tabs, item1 and item2. I would like to programatically add new tabs through the TabPanel's add() method. I am unclear how to access the tabpanel's methods however after extending.

Comment: You should be able to call add() on DVI.DviDashboard instance as if it were a TabPanel.

Comment: It says that DVI.DviDashboard.add is not a function. When I debug in Firebug, I do not see the method listed.

Comment: Yes, `DVI.DviDashboard.add` is definitely not a function. It's a class defining your TabPanel. As @amol said, 'you should be able to call add() on DVI.DviDashboard __instance__ as if it were a  TabPanel'. You need to call `add` on the instance that you have created, not to the class itself. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating the DviDashboard using xtype like this:

```
tabPanel = {xtype: dviDashboard}
```

The function I wrote to add tabs to this panel originally looked like this:

```
function buildDecisionMatrix() {

    var db = new DVI.DviDashboard();

    db.add({
       title: 'New Tab',
       xtype: 'grid',
       iconCls: 'tabs',
       html: 'Tab Body',
       closable: true
    });
    db.doLayout();
}
```

Problem was doLayout() was not rebuilding the panel with the tab. So I modified the creation of the tabPanel with an id:

```
tabPanel = {xtype: dviDashboard, id: 'dviDashboard'}
```

So I was able to get the tabPanel as a component. Then the function I build to add the tab was modified like so:

```
function buildDecisionMatrix() {

    //var db = new DVI.DviDashboard();

    var db = Ext.getCmp('dviDashboard')

    var newDb = db.add({
       title: 'New Tab',
       xtype: 'grid',
       iconCls: 'tabs',
       html: 'Tab Body',
       closable: true
    });
    db.doLayout();
    dv.setActiveTab(newDb);
}
```

And this worked. Thanks to all that responded.

Answer (score 1):

(Stolen @amol's answer)

It'll be as simple as calling `.add` on the instance.

In the following example, you may want to check out how I access the instance through `this` from the change of scope. You may want to read up more about the [event handling by checking out this manual](http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Manual%3aIntro%3aEvent_Handling)

Example code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/UxQaK/)

```
var DVI = {};
DVI.DviDashboard = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            activeTab: 0,
            items: [{
                title: 'Tab 1',
                html: 'Tab 1'
            }, {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: 'Tab 2'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Add Tab',
                handler: function() {
                    var content = 'Tab '+(this.items.getCount()+1);
                    this.add(new Ext.Panel({
                        title: content,
                        html: content 
                    }));
                    this.setActiveTab(this.items.getCount()-1);
                },
                //This 'this' is referring to your tabpanel, and by doing so,
                //the 'this' in your button's handler function is in fact the object
                //that you've set here, which is, the tabpabel itself.
                scope: this
            }]
        });

        DVI.DviDashboard.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

    }
});

Ext.reg('dviDashboard', DVI.DviDashboard);

var dviDashboard = new DVI.DviDashboard({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. In my case, the tabpanel is already rendered so I cannot render it again. I understand that add() is a method of the instance of the class. How can I access the existing instance to call the add() method?

Answer (score 1):

Your instance of `DVI.DviDashboard` *is* a TabPanel, so you can treat it as such:

```
var dashboard = new DVI.DviDashboard();
dashboard.add(otherTab);
```

UPDATE:

Make sure you call `tabPanel.doLayout()` after adding a new tab, so that the tab gets rendered and laid out.  Ext waits for you to call `doLayout()` in case you want to add tabs in batch fashion.

Comment: Problem now is getting the new tab to render. I dump dashboard to the console and as expected has the add() method. However, when I call the method, no tab appears. Inspecting the dom after I run the method shows the tab exists, but it does not appear. Note I have called the show() method as such: dashboard.add(newTab).show() then the doLayout method as such: dashboard.doLayout()

Comment: Which note?  Your edited comment?  There shouldn't be any need to call the `show()` function.  Just do `dashboard.add(otherTab);`, then `dashboard.doLayout()`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code used to add the tab:

```
function buildDecisionMatrix() {

    var db = new DVI.DviDashboard();

    db.add({
        title: 'New Tab',
        xtype: 'grid',
        iconCls: 'tabs',
        html: 'Tab Body',
        closable: true
    }).show();
    db.doLayout();
}
```

When I execute the function, the DOM shows the tab created but the tab is not displayed. Perhaps I am calling the doLayout() method on the wrong thing?